# how to toggle react-navigation drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation https://reactnavigation.org/ for my first react-native project. I would like to toggle my drawer (open & close), but I have no idea how I can achieve this. I've been looking at the documentation from reactnavigation.org, but can't really find any hints.

Comment: did you do this?

Answer (score 6):

As by React Navigation(v2)

**To open and close drawer, use the following helpers to open and close the drawer:**

```
this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
```

**If you would like to toggle the drawer you call the following:**

```
this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
```

**Each of these functions, behind the scenes, are simply dispatching actions:**

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer());
```

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to toggle the drawer you can navigate to 'DrawerToggle', and this will choose which navigation is appropriate for you given the drawers current state.

fires 'DrawerOpen&DrawerClose' accordingly

> **this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle');**

Answer (score 3):

As per [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation.html):

> To open and close drawer, navigate to 'DrawerOpen' and 'DrawerClose' respectively.
>
> ```
> this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); // open drawer
> this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose'); // close drawer
> ```

Comment: yes, saw this, but how can I check drawer is open/close state?

Comment: Know this is extremely late, not sure if you were ever able to find the answer for this but this is the way that React Navigation recommends you find the state of the drawer. 

const parent = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
const isDrawerOpen = parent && parent.state && parent.state.isDrawerOpen;

Answer (score 2):

Look into this.props.navigation.state.  You should be able to find 'DrawerOpen' or 'DrawerClose' in the routeName as in this [example](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/Drawer/DrawerView.js).

Answer (score 2):

For version 5.x:

import DrawerActions:

`import { DrawerActions } from "@react-navigation/native";`

and you can use `navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())`